# How to hide PHP if database is empty

Tags: php, database

How can I make the twitter and facebook links NOT DISPLAY if empty in database?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$links=explode(" ",preg_replace("|\s|Umxis", ' ', $r['web_links']));
if(count($links)>0){
echo "<div id='profile_links'>
<h3>Websites:</h3>
<ul class='profile_links'>";
foreach($links as $k=>$v){
echo "<li><a href='$v'>$v</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>
</div>
<a class='fb_link' href='http://{$r['facebook']}'</a>
<a class='tw_link' href='http://www.twitter.com/{$r['twitter']}'</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What does "if empty in database" mean?

Comment: `Umxis`? Are you just tacking modifiers on for the fun of it? I think none of those has any effect on your regex.

Comment: @deceze: When in doubt... MOAR!

Comment: Presumably you need an `if` statement inside your `foreach`; something like `if ($v) { echo ... }`.

Comment: Or, if the links you refer to are in fact the two `<a>` tags at the end, these too can have if statements wrapped around them. Try `<?php if ($r['facebook']): ?>` and `<?php endif ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

What about an isset?!

```
<?php
$links=explode(" ",preg_replace("|\s|Umxis", ' ', $r['web_links']));
if(count($links)>0){
echo "<div id='profile_links'>
<h3>Websites:</h3>
<ul class='profile_links'>";
foreach($links as $k=>$v){
echo "<li><a href='$v'>$v</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>
</div>";
if (isset($r['facebook']) && ! empty($r['facebook'])) {
    echo "<a class='fb_link' href='http://{$r['facebook']}'</a>";
}
if (isset($r['facebook']) && ! empty($r['facebook'])) {
    echo "<a class='tw_link' href='http://www.twitter.com/{$r['twitter']}'</a>";
}
}
?
```

>